# issue with trigger function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a trigger function after items are inserted into a table but i am getting a syntax error and not sure what is going on. Can someone please help? Here is my syntax:

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON  [DR].[dbo].[Derived_Values]
FOR INSERT
AS  
    declare @BusinessUnit varchar(75);
    declare @Questions varchar(max);
    declare @Answer nchar(10);


    select @BusinessUnit=i.@BusinessUnit from inserted i;   
select @Questions=i.@Questions from inserted i; 
select @Answer=i.@Answer from inserted i;   


    insert into [Main].[dbo].[Derived_Values_Test]
           (BusinessUnit,Questions, Answer) 
    values(@BusinessUnit,@Questions, @Answer);

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: here is error:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trgAfterInsert, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '@BusinessUnit'.

Comment: `select @BusinessUnit=i.@BusinessUnit from inserted i;` Is your column really called `@BusinessUnit`?

Comment: yes it is called BusinessUnit

Comment: @moe Then it should probably be `select @BusinessUnit=i.BusinessUnit from inserted i;`, however @sqlvogel's answer below has a better way of doing the entire thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON  [DR].[dbo].[Derived_Values]
FOR INSERT
AS  
    insert into [Main].[dbo].[Derived_Values_Test]
           (BusinessUnit,Questions, Answer) 
    SELECT BusinessUnit,Questions, Answer
    FROM inserted;

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
```

Never write triggers like yours which effectively assumes there will only be one row updated. Triggers should use set based logic.

Comment: thnx, i have tried your method and i did not get any error when i run it but it did not create the trigger in that database.  Do i need to declare variables first or this is all what i need.  not sure why it did not create the trigger

Comment: You don't need any variables at all. Trigger gets created in the database where you run the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

Comment: thanks.  I am inserting the data a table that is remote server so when i run it i get this error ""The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions."." Do you know what i need to do in order to resolve this?  thanks

Comment: If the target is a linked server then I suggest you don't use triggers because that will require a distributed transaction. Use a proc outside a transaction. Or use some other process to replicate the data (Service Broker, SSIS, or even just a remote view on the target server).

Answer (score 0):

`@Answer` is declared as a string, not a table.  So this will not work:

```
select @Answer=i.@Questions from @Answer i;
```

Should this be `inserted`?

```
select @Answer=i.@Questions from inserted i;
```

Also, you appear to be using variables for column names:

```
select @BusinessUnit=i.BusinessUnit from inserted i;   
select @Questions=i.Questions from inserted i; 
select @Answer=i.Answerfrom inserted i;
```

Comment: guys i am sorry i don't know how that happened but i updated now all my select statement but still getting the same error. see my initial post. thanks